# complicated form

Tags: forms

```
\documentclass{complicatedform}
%title{Writing a LaTeX Class File to Produce a Form}
\begin{document}
\collaborator{Dr A Person}{CMP}{1234}
\collaborator{Prof A.N. Other}{ENV}{5678}
\otherfunding{This proposal has also been submitted to
the intergalactic federation of Nog last year.}
\begin{projectdescription}
This is a really interesting project!
\end{projectdescription}
\training{The student will be trained in intergalactic space 
exploration.}
\monitored{Telepathically}
\end{document}
```

error, File `complicatedform.cls' not found. \begin

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable.  Also, add a real question.

Comment: You need to have the `complicatedform` document class, which I could trace down to http://www.latex-community.org/know-how/latex/54-latex-document-classes/342-writing-a-latex-class-file-to-produce-a-form. Download the file and save it somewhere TeX can find it (your current working directory, for example).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is solved by  Gonzalo Medina comment